# Does SQL Server CE (local db) of Windows Phone 7.5 support triggers?

Tags: sql-server-ce, windows-ce, windows-phone-7

This seems stupid but still need to clear my doubt whether local db (SQL Server CE) of Windows Phone 7.5 support triggers.

I have found that SQL Server CE does not support triggers.

So for triggers I am using SQLite in Windows Phone 7.5

Same is there any harm in using sqlite with triggers or may I frame like this
Can I have a way to use something like triggers in SQL Server CE?

Thanks and regards,
Kanaya

Comment: How are you wanting to use the triggers? It may just be better to code up what you were going to do in the trigger as part of your code.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but as in case of windows phone triggers will make my App more responsive, and not wait for database queries to finish. I can do the same task by async, but wont triggers me a plus thing.

Comment: Sounds like you might be trying to solve your problem the "wrong" way, but as you don't really give any detail, it's difficult to advise.

Comment: Ok, here the scenario in brief:- data entered by user, get inserted in table. I want to upload this data to various web platforms so what I do is I have written a trigger which inserts this data to another table called uploads and has flags for each web platform whether uploaded or not. This is done as there may not be network available sometimes or the website down whatever. And user data comes from many forms on UI.

Comment: It sounds like you have more tables than you need -- Why not just have the uploaded flags alongside? - you can then have your background process handling the upload no problem.

Comment: You can even use a Background agent in Mango

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  SQL Server Compact, incuding the version on the Phone, does not support triggers, stored procedures or views.  You'll have to find a different mechanism to achieve what you want (like a BackgroundAgent).

Comment: Thank you very much for your staright answer. In all it seems everyone is opposing me to use sqlite which have triggers and use background agents instead? Wouldn't background resources consume phone resources(CPU, battery) in background?